# changing viewmodel's MetadataType attribute at runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

In Microsoft MVC 3.0,I have a class:

```
public class Product{
    public string Title {get;set;}
}
```

This class can be represent as Product or as Service , the only difference between them is just the field labels at View time.

so I create two classes :

```
 public class ProductMetaData
    {
        [Display(Name = "Product")]
        public object Title { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
public class ServiceMetaData
    {
        [Display(Name = "Service")]
        public object Title { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I set these classes at runtime as **MetadataType**?

**------------------------ EDIT --------------------------**

I found we can set/change metadata for a type through inheriting **DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider** and **DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider** classes and overriding **GetTypeDescriptor** method in both like this:

```
 public class xx : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{

    protected override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type type)
    {

        if (type == typeof(InvoiceItemViewModel))
            return (new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(InvoiceItemViewModel), typeof(InvoiceItemMetaData))).GetTypeDescriptor(type);
        else
            return base.GetTypeDescriptor(type);
    }
}

 public class yy : DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider
{

    protected override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type type)
    {

        if (type == typeof(InvoiceItemViewModel))
            return (new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(InvoiceItemViewModel), typeof(InvoiceItemMetaData))).GetTypeDescriptor(type);
        else
            return base.GetTypeDescriptor(type);
    }

}
```

And the following changes in Global.ascx

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new xx();

ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new yy());
```

BUT the question is how can depend it on **Model Instance** and not just type?!...As I see there is no any access to **Model** through these classes. Is there any place in MVC pipleline to change these two provider classess based on Model data? (for example in : OnActionExecuting or something else?)

Answer (score 5):

You could write a [custom model metadata provider](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=715). For example you may take a look at [MvcExtensions](http://mvcextensions.codeplex.com/). They implemented [such provider](http://mvcextensions.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/f71bcadf0e76#Trunk/MvcExtensions/ModelMetadata/ExtendedModelMetadataProvider.cs) in order to be able to dynamically associate metadata to a given type at runtime. The same technique is used by [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/).

Comment: ow! too complicated for this simple task! I prefer to find a workaround for it!

Comment: @MahmoudMoravej, that's the reason why I don't use DataAnnotations to perform validation in my applications. I use FluentValidation.NET.